# Hyper-V VM extremely slow - 100% disk usage always

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, performance, virtualization, hyper-v

Windows 10 Pro host

Windows 10 Developer VM

Operations related to installing/removing applications are extremely slow on my VM and task manager shows disk usage always at 100%, average response time is between 80 - 250ms. CPU usage never gets above 2 - 5% and memory normally stays below 80%. I've tried messing around with RAM starting off with 2gb allocated and eventually trying 8gb allocation with no effect. My host has 32gb RAM.

So given this I can only assume that my RAM/CPU configurations aren't issue and there's something else wrong. I've read many posts online and tried suggested solutions but nothing I find has made any difference. I've been using VirtualBox up until now and the performance of those VMs have been infinitely better, I've read that Hyper-V is generally meant to be faster so I guess this further suggests there might be a misconfiguration somewhere.

How can I improve/troubleshoot my VMs performance?

Comment: check pagefile size, maybe increase it a bit. Disable services: Sysmain (used to be superfetch), wsearch, bits, windows update. Turn off defender live scanning.

Comment: What the Windows versions? Add on your post.

Comment: What VHDX type did you create? Is it fixed one? Check AV settings. It could have negative influence on the performance. What is your storage? HDD or SSD. Measure performance of the underlying storage and compare it with the performance inside of the VM. Might help: https://www.hyper-v.io/several-tips-hints-full-throttle-hyper-v-performance/